# Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Database first and Generated column

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

in my table I have a Generated column of Decimal type,

```
COLUMN `quantidadeTotal` DECIMAL(18,4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((`quantidade` + `quantidadeReservada`) + `quantidadeBloqueada`)) VIRTUAL;
```

which is the sum of 3 other columns also of Decimal type, the problem occurs when I execute "scaffold", the generated model comes with this column in this format

```
public decimal? QuantidadeTotal { get; set; }
```

and in generated context also has reference to the

```
entity.Property(e => e.QuantidadeTotal)
.HasColumnName("quantidadeTotal")
.HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)");
```

column
if i try to insert some record in the table i get an error, even if not informing anything in the Generated column, i have to delete the reference of this column in the context and in the model to work.
is there any configuration for scaffold to ignore this type of column or any special treatment?

if not, every time I make a scaffold I will have to adjust all fields manually, and it would be a lot of work.

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v3.2.4

thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a bug in `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`. Please file an issue on our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/) (you can just copy the title and content from here as is). Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are scaffolding more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this bug on our [repository](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) as [Database first and Generated column #1256](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1256)!

We fixed it with:

- 3.2.x: [Add scaffolding support for computed columns #1257](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/1257)
- 5.0.0+: [Add scaffolding support for computed columns, including STORED support #1260](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/1260)